# Angularjs routconfig for different pages than specified in otherwise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Usually we have following type of config for route in angularjs:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        //Setting up HTML pages and controllers depending upon the suffix in the URL
        $routeProvider.
        when('/xyz', {
            templateUrl: '/etc/topproducts.html',
            controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/abc/:alphabet?', {
            templateUrl: '/etc/allproducts.html',
            controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/xyz'
        });
    }
]);
```

So if user goes to homepage then he gets redirected to topproducts.html and if he/she types /abc in url then user is shown allproducts.html in my case.

My question how to control which page to be shown if user types unexpected path in url like /blahblah

Since in my config above, otherwise({ is pointing to xyz, user is landing on topproducts.html. I want user to be shown different pages when user types /blahblah and /

Comment: otherwise is for unexpected path. Redirect the url inside otherwise and in that url define your page what you want to show for unexpected.

Comment: but angular won't tell me user typed /blahblah. the url will be changed by angular from /blahblah to /xyz. You think this can be done by adding one more when clause with some regular expression stuff?

Comment: Got your point now. You dont want to change the url what user types in url.
You want to show some content at that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could understand your problem then you want to Show Page Not Found, if that Url or page doee not exits in config.

Try below

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    //Setting up HTML pages and controllers depending upon the suffix in the URL
    $routeProvider.
    when('/xyz', {
        templateUrl: '/etc/topproducts.html',
        controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/abc/:alphabet?', {
        templateUrl: '/etc/allproducts.html',
        controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
         templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + '404.html',
         controller: '404'
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Your 404 controller will be

```
app.controller('404', function() {
      document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Page not found | AngularJS Demo Theme';
 });
```

And template can be

```
<h1>Page Not Found</h1>
<p>Sorry, but nothing can be found at this location.</p>
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in your code:

```
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/xyz'
});
```

This part means that if a user types anything other than what you specified in your route config, he will be redirected to `/xyz`

**Update** Do something like this:

```
when('/unexpected', {
    templateUrl: '/unexpected.html',
    controller: 'UnexpectedCtrl'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/unexpected'
})
```

Comment: but angular won't tell me user typed /blahblah. the url will be changed by angular from /blahblah to /xyz. You think this can be done by adding one more when clause with some regular expression stuff?

Comment: @Sandeep, not sure about what you want to do, but still take a look at my update. If this is not what you want, can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Available Approach 1 :**

I wish you could have use angular ui-Router than default once in your angular app. If it's still feasible to do it than you can transform it.They do have an available feature to fulfill what you wants to achieve here. You can handle it easily in this way.

$urlRouteProvider.rule() : Here you [go](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) for the documentation and for how to [use](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) it.

**Available Approach 2 :**

With your existing default urlRouterProvider, configure like this 
.when('/',) and than $routeParams will contain everything that is appended by user in url which internally keeps watch on $location.

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All
>   characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches. path can contain named
>   groups starting with a colon and ending with a star: e.g.:name*. All
>   characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name
>   when the route matches.

Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A67EbeUHS0QgiJksvsel?p=info) with $routeParams.

```
 App.controller("ChildCtrl1",function  ($scope,$routeParams) {
     $scope.message = "Link 1 has been Visited";
     $scope.debug = $routeParams;
 });
```